# Set a boolean (single on/off checkbox) value while creating a node

Tags: nodes

I am creating a node (in Drupal 8) with the following code.

```
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$node = Node::create([
            'type' => 'calendar_data',
            'title' => 'testing finaly 1111111111111111111111111 ',
            'field_current_month' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'field_date_type_value' => '1',
        ]);
$node->save();
```

The value of field_date_type_value is set to 0, not the expected value (1) I am using in the code.

Comment: Are you sure it's called `field_date_type_value` and not `field_date_type`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response, but I had the same problem few days ago. What worked for me was first of all creating the node and then setting the boolean value:

```
$node = Node::create([
  'type' => 'calendar_data',
  'title' => 'testing finaly 1111111111111111111111111 ',
  'field_current_month' => date('Y-m-d'),
]);
$node->field_date_type_value->value = TRUE;

$node->save();
```

The 'inline' field setting didn't work neither for some other fields for me. But the explicit version is working very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$node = Node::create([
        'type' => 'calendar_data',
        'title' => 'testing finaly 1111111111111111111111111 ',
        'field_current_month' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'field_date_type_value' => ['value' => '1'],
    ]);

$node->save();
```